# Racket built-in repetition functions

Tags: racket

I was looking for a way to repeat a function call a certain number of times and accumulate the results in a list and couldn't find anything in the standard library, so I wrote one. It's simple to write, but it seems like such an obvious thing that I feel like there must be an accepted way of doing this using standard library functions.

Here are the two functions I'm looking to replace:

```
(define (repeat n f)
  (unless (<= n 0)
    (f)
    (repeat (sub1 n) f)))

(define (accumulate n f)
  (let loop ([n n] [l empty])
    (if (<= n 0)
        l
        (loop (sub1 n)
              (cons (f) l)))))
```

Is there any simpler way of achieving this?

Comment: Maybe `(for/list ([i n]) (f i))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your function does not any take arguments, you can use [build-list](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Flist..rkt%29._build-list%29%29)

Example:

```
#lang racket

;; The function you want to call many times
(define (f)
  #t)

;; Use build list with a lambda to wrap your function because
;; build-list want a function takin integer as its second argument
(build-list 5 (lambda (x) (f)))
```

result:

```
'(#t #t #t #t #t)
```

Edit: you can also define a function to wrap the lambda

```
(define (repeat-then-accumulate n f)
  (build-list n (lambda (x) (f)))
  )
```

Usage:

```
;; Using the f function defined earlier
(repeat-then-accumulate 10 f)
```

result:

```
'(#t #t #t #t #t #t #t #t #t #t)
```

Edit2: If you want to have fixed args, you could do something like

```
#lang racket

;; The function you want to call many times
(define (f a b)
  (+ a b))


(define (repeat-then-accumulate n f args)
  (build-list n (lambda (x) (apply f args)))
  )
```

Usage:

```
(repeat-then-accumulate 10 f '(3 5))
```

Result:

```
'(8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8)
```

Answer (score 3):

It looks like @AlexKnauth didn't feel like taking your internet points for his answer, and he phrased it as a comment. I'm not proud, though... Use racket's list comprehension form:

```
(for/list ([i (in-range n)]) (f i))
```

(I added an explicit "in-range", just to get better error-checking.)

Comment: Maybe I understood the question wrongly, but in the example of OP, f doesn't take any parameters and in your example it does. Maybe more like  `(for/list ([i (in-range n)]) (f))`?

Comment: Great solution! I'm glad to know about `(in-range)` and `(for/list)`. However, I'm going to accept @JulienRousé's answer because I think `(build-list)` is a little closer to what I'm looking for. Given you an upvote though, and will definitely use this for other things in future. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just throwing in my own two cents here.

Use either `foldl` or `foldr` if you want to include the result in each repetition.

```lisp
;; Just a demo function to showcase the repeater. It moves the first item to the back of the list, like a rotating bit shift
(define (rotate-list lst)
  (append (rest lst) (list (first lst))))

(define (repeat fn times default)
  (let ((rang (range times)))
    (foldl (lambda (_ res) (fn res)) default rang)))

(repeat rotate-list 5 '(the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog))
; result: '(jumps over the lazy dog the quick brown fox)
```

Or, if you want `repeat` to instead return a function, so it instead creates a new function that applies the other one n times:

```lisp
(define (repeat fn times)
  (let ((rang (range times)))
    (lambda (default) (foldl (lambda (_ res) (fn res)) default rang))))

(define rotate-five-times (repeat rotate-list 5))

(rotate-five-times '(the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog))
; result: '(jumps over the lazy dog the quick brown fox)
```